# Creating a Microsoft Azure SQL Database creates both SQL Server and SQL Database resources

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I've always thought Azure SQL DB is a single product and hence a single resource on Azure.
However i noticed that when creating an Azure SQL DB instance, it creates a SQL Server resource and a SQL Database resource in my resource group.

What's the relationship between them? 
Any documentations on this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an Azure SQL server resource in order to have the SQL Database resource (since one is dependent on the other).

You can create a new instance or reuse existing instance. things like firewalls, backups, etc are tied to the db instance to some extent

I was unable to find a specific document that talks about this, but the topic covering creating a database covers the server as well: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-single-database-get-started?tabs=azure-portal

For example, this article covers single server limits: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-resource-limits-database-server#maximum-resource-limits

Comment: thank you! i found the documentation for SQL server and it explains how its a central admin, management point for single, multiple SQL databases and how its a logical parent resource etc. to a db. check out the answer for the link.

Answer (score 0):

Link to documentation on understanding the relationship between SQL server (parent) and SQL database resources on Azure: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-servers